# sum of all elements in hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am given a hash with values as an array of integers. I want to add all values of same index in my result. The length of all arrays in hash values is same.
For ex,

```
hash = {
 "A" => [1,2,3],
 "B" => [1,2,3],
 "C" => [1,2,3]
}
```

Then the resultant array i want,adding all same index elements together will be [3,6,9].

Is there any efficient way to do this in ruby ?? Or looping over the keys and array elements is the best possible solution ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
hash.values.transpose.map { |r| r.reduce(:+) }
  #=> [3,6,9]
```

Another would be:

```
values = hash.values
values.shift.zip(*values).map { |r| r.reduce(:+) } 
  #=> [3,6,9]
```

If you'd prefer using using [linear algebra](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html), you could do this:

```
require 'matrix'
(Matrix.row_vector([1]*hash.size)*Matrix[*hash.values]).row(0).to_a
  #=> [3, 6, 9]
```